# ASP.NET Core layered architecture and IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-core

I have multiple layers (projects) created like `MyProject.Data`, `MyProject.API`. In `MyProject.Data` I store all the models that will be used in the `MyProject.API`.

What should I do with extended IdentityUser? Should I put it inside `MyProject.Data` or `MyProject.API`? The problem with putting it in my data layer is that it creates a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores`

`class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`

Sorry if the question sounds stupid but for some reason I have such a concern.

Comment: Are you planning to use this application user all across your enterprise or just in the API? Also where is the context that you are going to use to write this class to the DB going to be?

Comment: @DerekHackett I'm planning to use this user in other layers not only API. The context is in `MyProject.Data`

Comment: It is common practice to keep the models being written to the DB with the context even if it is a user and adds that reference.